# pivot OLAP based, read visible items list

Tags: vba, pivot, pivot-table, filtering, datamodel

I have a pivot table that is connected to cube. My main goal is to go through all filters in this pivot and download a list of all filtered elements.
[image: pivot_filters]

I have this part of the code:

```
Dim pv As PivotTable
Set pv = Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

'read data from filters section
For Each ffield In pv.PageFields

On Error Resume Next
a = ffield.Name

        'to check if in filter there is "multiple item" selected we have to shorten the string
        'eg. if filter field is [Service Line].[Function].[SubFunction] (hierarchy)
        'we have to check only CubeFields [Service Line].[Function]

        reverse_a = StrReverse(a)
        first_dot = Application.Find(".", reverse_a)
        proper_string = Left(a, Len(a) - first_dot)
        
is_marked_multiple = pv.CubeFields(proper_string).EnableMultiplePageItems

    'to list all item that are selected with multiple item we use
    'visibleitemlist method
    'if multiple item is not checked we use
    'currentpagename method
    
    If is_marked_multiple Then
   
        items_filtered = pv.PivotFields(a).VisibleItemsList
    Else
        items_filtered = pv.PivotFields(a).CurrentPageName
    End If

Next
```

Everything is ok when I have filtered some data with multiple items checked - macro uses "VisibleItemsList" method

eg: [image: multiple_items_filtered]

output: [image: multiple_items_filtered_output]

If multiple item is not checked it also works fine - it uses "CurrentPageName" method:

eg: [image: single_item_filtered]

output: [image: single_item_filtered_output]

The problem is when I have checked multiple items selection and I have nothing filtered (meaning all is selected)

eg: [image: all_with_multiple_filtered]

output: [image: all_with_multiple_filtered]

the output is just an empty string...

What am I doing wrong in this case?
I need the filter fields because based on this I am creating other table.

I would appreciate any comments/links to help me with the case!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi!
Still no... I just did some extra condition
If the filtered_items is empty and there is selected multiple_items
I just first "uncheck" multiple_items and read the filtered items again. 

It works, but I would really like to know how to do it "PROPERLY" and also to understand, why it works like this...